# MySQL Delete query doesn't come to an end

Tags: sql, mysqli

I am running a select query on My SQL Server for select as below.

```
select * 
from tabl1 
where U_ID = '2345'
```

Above query is taking only 1 sec.

But when I am doing delete for same i.e:

```
delete from tabl1 
where U_ID = '2345'
```

it keeps on executing.

What could be the reason? Any ideas?

Comment: Post more information: table schema, number of records, output of checking the query planner, etc. Consider that just returning data does not have to update the log, but deleting does, and so on.

Comment: Do you have any indices defined on this table?

Comment: Table has around 25 columns and has 103292 number of records. With all proper  indexes. The id for which i am filtering has only 250 records.

Comment: Are there any records in tabl1 locking that U_ID?  Select can often do a dirty read allowing one to access the data while another user is "editing it"  However, if you try to delete data that is being edited by another user; the database must wait to perform the delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database writes are expensive than reads.

If there are any indexes , try disabling the indexes. Run your Query and after that , re-build the indexs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be so many depending on the error you are getting.

- Try to Restart MSSQL SEVER Service & check again.
- Also check the structure of the table you're deleting, because of too many references data can take long time to delete aswell.

Better you post ERROR you're getting.